# I have a 403 error - client denied by server configuration

Tags: javascript, php, apache, wamp

On the local development server, a page calling an XML file to be used by spry for an autocomplete in a form is generating a 403 error (on the production server it works).
Another instance on the development server, with only small differences, is working OK.  Both are in the same Bitnami Wamp stack and the conf files are the same except for the first line:

```
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
```

I've tried to find differences in the HTML/PHP between the two that could cause it but cannot see anything that might do this

The line that calls the xml file
`var dsStores1 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("../data/stores/stores_01.xml?' . $anti_cache . '", "/stores/store", { sortOnLoad: "store_name" });`

The autocomplete script does nor run and the error log shows that the required xml file is not loaded:
`[Wed Jul 10 09:42:59.620425 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 15264:tid 916] [client 127.0.0.1:51085] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: W:/sites/site1/data/stores/stores_1.xml, referer: http://127.0.0.1/site1/jobs/new.php`

In the access log it shows as `sun - - [10/Jul/2019:08:55:05 +0100] "GET /site1/data/stores/stores_1.xml?304 HTTP/1.1" 403 242` whereas all other lines begin with the local IP 127.0.0.1 e.g. `127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2019:08:14:07 +0100] "GET /site2/files/xml/stores_2.xml?844 HTTP/1.1" 200 234543`

The computer (Win7) on which the server is installed is named SUN.

Comment: A 403 error is an access forbidden error - and you say it's a local server? Odd. Try clearing your cache, cookies, the lot, and retry.  If no joy, I'd contact your ISP ..

Comment: Do you have the same modules enabled? `mod_version` specifically, since the access rules themselves look fine. However, unless you have a mixed environment with different apache versions I wouldn't use `IfVersion` but target your apache version directly.

Comment: Hi Rachel, clearing the cached and cookies has no effect, and the server is installed  on my computer, so outside the scope of my ISP

Comment: msg - both sites use the same httpd.conf file, so all modules are identical.  I've removed the `Ifversion` but that has not changed anything.